# Countdown timer in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime, timer, difference

I'm having a start time as `11:30:25PM`  and an end time as `11:45:25AM`

So now I would like to get the diff between the end time and the start time

This is what I have used the below code and working pretty well:

```
Dim dFrom As DateTime
Dim dTo As DateTime
Dim sDateFrom As String = Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")
Dim sDateTo As String = txtlogout1.Text
If DateTime.TryParse(sDateFrom, dFrom) AndAlso DateTime.TryParse(sDateTo, dTo) Then
    Timer1.Start()
    Dim TS As TimeSpan = dTo - dFrom
    Dim hour As Integer = TS.Hours
    Dim mins As Integer = TS.Minutes
    Dim secs As Integer = TS.Seconds
    Dim timeDiff As String = ((hour.ToString("00") & ":") + mins.ToString("00") & ":") + secs.ToString("00")
    txtremaining1.Text = timeDiff
End If
```

Now the problem is if the start time is `11:30:25PM` and the end time is `12:00:25AM` then the remaining time is showing as `-23:30:00`

So what's the correct way of handling this?

Comment: I hope you're not using a Timer for your countdown: [The use of System.Windows.Forms.Timer for Time](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9ddb2f16-796a-483a-aa3f-0f9b959e0eea/the-use-of-systemwindowsformstimer-for-time?forum=vbgeneral).

Answer (score 0):

Are you only concerned about spanning one day? Could you just check whether your `Timespan` variable is negative, and add a day if it is?

```
If TS.TotalMilliseconds < 0 Then TS = TS.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If DateTime.TryParse(txtlogout1.text, dTo) Then
    Dim ts as Timespan = dTo.Subtract(DateTime.now)
    If ts.TotalMilliseconds < 0 Then ts = ts.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(1))
    txtremaining1.Text = ts.ToString()
End If
```

Comment: Could you add more detail to this answer, please?